# Identifying nodes with many, but thin connections

Tags: neo4j, graph-data-science

I need to identify (and label) nodes with many relationships (say, 10 on a possible scale of 1 to 60) but weak weights for the relationships (say 1 or 2 on a possible scale of 1 to 100). I could write a Cypher query to find them. I don’t need help with that. What I want to ask is, is there a GDS metric for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of degree and weighted degree.

If you want to construct such a gds graph, you could use the subgraph option that allows you to filter on mutated properties